# Solving PDE containing mixed partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

I want to solve the PDE

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t\,\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},\quad -\infty < x < \infty,$$

$$u(x,0) = e^{-\lvert x\rvert}.$$

without the final answer involving integrals. The problem has a mixed partial derivatives, how can I handle that?

Comment: What does separation of variables get you?

Comment: I don't know how to apply separation of variables to this. Is it possible when the derivative is mixed?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t\,\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
Let $\quad v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
This is a first order linear PDE which general solution is wellknown :
$$v(x,t)=f(x+t)$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary function.
$$u=\int f(x-t)dx=F(x+t)+g(t)$$
$F$ and $g$  are arbitrary functions. They have to be determined according to the condition $u(x,0) = e^{-\lvert x\rvert}.$
$$u(x,0)=F(x)+g(0)=e^{-\lvert x\rvert}$$
$$F(x)=e^{-\lvert x\rvert}-g(0)$$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above equation $u=F(x+t)+g(t)$ where the argument of $F$ is $(x+t)$.
$$u(x,t)=e^{-\lvert x+t\rvert}+g(t)-g(0)$$
This is the solution satisfying both the PDE and the solution. Thus the solution is not unique since they are infinity many functions $g(t)$. The specified condition is not suffisant to determine a unique solution.

Comment: Thank you so much.